# Space above and below HTML table varies largely from Google Chrome to Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, wordpress, spacing

On the website https://neu.seidelpartner.ch/ I have the following HTML table which is inserted into a WordPress text box:

```css
#kunden {
  border-spacing: 30px;
}

#cell1,
#cell2,
#cell3,
#cell4,
#cell5,
#cell6,
#cell7,
#cell8 {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #857f7b;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<table id="kunden">
  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="cell1">BAHNUNTERNEHMEN</td>
    <td id="cell2">BEHÖRDEN</td>
    <td id="cell3">GENOSSENSCHAFTEN</td>
    <td id="cell4">INVESTOREN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id=row2>
    <td id="cell5">PROJEKTENTWICKLER</td>
    <td id="cell6">IMMOBILIEN-ANLAGESTIFTUNGEN</td>
    <td id="cell7">KMU</td>
    <td id="cell8">PLANER</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now what I observed is that the space above and below the table varies largely from Google Chrome (first image, large space) to Microsoft Edge (second image, small space). Intended from my side is how it looks in Edge.

[image]
[image]

I did some research and it seems that such spacing differences occured to many people on different elements but I was not able to solve the issue by myself.

This is also my first contact with HTML and CSS. I did not really learned these from beginning but instead just researched what I needed.

Thank you very much for any feedback.

Regards

Comment: Looks exactly the same in edge v80 and chrome v80 (both have the large space on your site - not in the snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pete for changing the code to a snippet, I was not aware this is possible (very cool feature). Your comment made me look deeper into the issue and I could solve it myself.

There was a pseudoelement `::before` and `::after` above and below the table.

It was possible to remove it with:

```
div.gdlr-core-pbf-column-content.clearfix.gdlr-core-js::before {
    content: none;
}

div.gdlr-core-pbf-column-content.clearfix.gdlr-core-js::after {
    content: none;
}
```

Regards